# How to get current item from ng-repeat in md-select?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Briefly, my HTML is:

```
<md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block defaultInputSelect deskInputSelect" flex="auto">
    <md-select id="selectedClient" ng-model="actionData.client_id" required>
        <md-option ng-repeat="client in clientsList" value="{{client.id}}" ng-click="getResponsibleList(client)">
     {{client.second_name + ' ' + client.first_name}}
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

I need to extract current selected item `client` in controller. I can't get it from model, because only `client.id` stored there. I can't get it by clicking on option (using `ng-click="getResponsibleList(client)"`) because I need to get current item before user's interactions.

Comment: What if you just execute getResponsibleList(clientsList[0]) on the controller

Comment: @Juanín, good idea, but I can't use `0` index, I need to use the actual one. How can I find out what it is now? Without creating for-loop through clientsList using `actionData.client_id` of course. I believe, there must be simplier idea.

Comment: Can you post value for `clientsList` ?

Comment: But you just have to execute getResponsibleList(clientsList[0]) and then the ng-click will take care of executing it afterwards when the user clicks on it.

Comment: Why do you need to get the selected item before it's selected?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the property `$index` of ng-repeat :

```
`<md-option ng-repeat="client in clientsList" value="{{client.id}}" ng-click="getResponsibleList($index)" ... ` 

$scope.getResponsibleList = function(index){
       console.log(index);
}
```

some reading :

https://codeutopia.net/blog/2014/11/10/angularjs-best-practices-avoid-using-ng-repeats-index/

Comment: But how I will know which `$index` is currently selected if I didn't click yet?

Comment: why did you need to get the index before user click on it ??

Answer (score 0):

You should set value to client, not client.id and and **ng-model-option** to specify unique selector (id in this case) like:

```
<md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block defaultInputSelect deskInputSelect" flex="auto">
    <md-select 
        id="selectedClient" 
        ng-model="actionData.client_id"
        required
        >
        <md-option 
           ng-repeat="client in clientsList" 
           ng-value="client.id" 
           ng-click="getResponsibleList(client)"
        >
     {{client.second_name + ' ' + client.first_name}}
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

This way value will contain your selected client.

Comment: `actionData.client_id` is assigned to `ng-model` so you will be able to access it in controller with `actionData.client_id`.

Comment: @masitko, Sorry, but after this I can see all options in md-select simultaneously (comma separated).

Comment: @hva.narola, no, I need to extract `client` in controller while `client_id` still wil be stored in model.

Comment: just check if this works, I have a very similar code in my application and it works. You need to remember that after selection ng-model will contain whole client model not just id. If you still having problems can you post clientList please?

Comment: @masitko, I've checked. It causes a bug. I can see all options simultaneously inside md-select, they're comma separated.

Comment: Can you post your clientsList then? Console log or so

Comment: Actually can you try to change value to ng-value on md-select?

Comment: @masitko, changing `value` to `ng-value` fixed bug. But It assigns a client object to `actionData.client_id` instead of just id. This is not what I want. The actual question is: can I get a client object from my md-select without using model at all.

Comment: I've edited the code again, if this doesn't work try to use ng-change binded to md-select instead.